# should I use Box or Grid?

Tags: material-ui, grid, box

Should I be using Box/Component/Stack instead of Grid if I don't care about responsive design?

TL;DR

I am new to material ui.  I have been reading the online documentation, blogs and watching the videos.

I'm seeing a lot of people use the Grid for positioning and layout when the design is not intended to be responsive, as in, there will only ever be the one screen size.  In this case would it be better to use Box instead of Grid?

My current understanding is that Grid is for responsive design and Box/Container/Stack is for a non-responsive design.

Yes, I know all the designs should be responsive, but I'm working on a project that doesn't care about responsive design.

Thoughts, comments, suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Box and Grid in Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744735/what-is-the-difference-between-box-and-grid-in-material-ui)

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744735/what-is-the-difference-between-box-and-grid-in-material-ui

Comment: Both of the above do not answer the question. I think the question the op was meaning to ask was "If grid is used as the top level component for the app only then can responsive design be achieved or we can still make responsive apps even if we have a box as top level component, by using a grid inside the top level box?"